# Number of Lines Determined

Tags: geometry

Consider six coplanar points such that no four of them are collinear. What is the minimum number of lines that can be determined by them?

I calculate eight by arrange the points like this:

X

X  X
  X
X  X

Is there a way to get fewer than eight lines? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make 7 lines, but you can't make fewer.

[image: 7 lines]

It's impossible to do it with 5 lines. Each of five lines should pass through 3 points, so there are 15 tuples (line, point). By Dirichlet principle, one point should be in 2 or fewer tuples ($15/6 < 3$). So there is a point with only 2 lines. But one cannot distribute 5 other points between those two lines without making four points collinear.

Answer (score 0):

If no three points are colinear there will be ${6 \choose 5}=15$ lines.  For each line with three points on it you lose $2$ of these lines, so you want the maximum number of lines with three points.  I see nine lines in your figure, corresponding to three lines with three points each.  There are four from the top X, two horizontal, two diagonals through the X on the third line, and one vertical through the leftmost points.

There is no way to get four lines with three points each.  No point can be on three lines as it takes six other points to make three lines.  That means each point must be on two lines.  If the points are $a,b,c,d,e,f$ you can have lines $abc$ and $def$ but then the third line must have two points from one of these.